# Splice array of objects by max-length

Tags: javascript

There's an array of objects like

```
var a =[
{type: 't1', value: 'x1'},
{type: 't1', value: 'x2'},
{type: 't1', value: 'x3'},
{type: 't1', value: 'x4'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x5'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x1'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x2'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x3'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x4'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x5'}]
```

How to slice/splice/filter this array to make it return say first 3 items of type `t1` and first 4 items of `t2`?

Comment: I don't understand what that grouping has to do with max-length?

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296) . The bare minimum effort would be to run a `for` loop and check if item at a specific index has `type` as `t1`, add it to a `result` array. Then `break` the loop of the predefined count is reached. (TBH, this approach is faster than chaining `Array.prototype` methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) followed by [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
const a = [
  {type: 't1', value: 'x1'},
  {type: 't1', value: 'x2'},
  {type: 't1', value: 'x3'},
  {type: 't1', value: 'x4'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x5'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x1'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x2'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x3'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x4'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x5'}
];

const t1 = a.filter(x => x.type === 't1').slice(0, 3);
const t2 = a.filter(x => x.type === 't2').slice(0, 4);

console.log(t1);
console.log(t2);
```

Or use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const a = [
  {type: 't1', value: 'x1'},
  {type: 't1', value: 'x2'},
  {type: 't1', value: 'x3'},
  {type: 't1', value: 'x4'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x5'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x1'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x2'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x3'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x4'},
  {type: 't2', value: 'x5'}
];

const getByType = (arr, prop, num) =>
  arr.reduce(([out, i], x) => (match = x.type === prop, [
    match && i < num ? [...out, x] : out,
    match ? i + 1 : i
  ]),
  [[], 0])[0];

console.log(getByType(a, 't1', 3));
console.log(getByType(a, 't2', 4));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Pass `0` and number of items to `slice()` as parameters

```js
var a =[
{type: 't1', value: 'x1'},
{type: 't1', value: 'x2'},
{type: 't1', value: 'x3'},
{type: 't1', value: 'x4'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x5'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x1'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x2'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x3'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x4'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x5'}]

function items(type,num){
  return a.filter(x => x.type === type).slice(0,num);
}

console.log(items('t1',3));
console.log(items('t2',4));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is rough. but works.

```js
var a =[
{type: 't1', value: 'x1'},
{type: 't1', value: 'x2'},
{type: 't1', value: 'x3'},
{type: 't1', value: 'x4'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x5'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x1'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x2'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x3'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x4'},
{type: 't2', value: 'x5'}];

let b = a.filter(x => x.type === 't1').slice(0,3).concat(a.filter(x => x.type === 't2').slice(0,4));

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make custom function using `reduce` method that creates one object and then you can return `Object.values`.

```js
var a = [{ type: 't1', value: 'x1' },{ type: 't1', value: 'x2' },{ type: 't1', value: 'x3' },{ type: 't1', value: 'x4' },{ type: 't2', value: 'x5' },{ type: 't2', value: 'x1' },{ type: 't2', value: 'x2' },{ type: 't2', value: 'x3' },{ type: 't2', value: 'x4' },{ type: 't2', value: 'x5' }];

function sliceArr(arr, slice) {
  const obj = arr.reduce((r, { type, ...rest }) => {
    if(slice[type]) {
      if(!r[type]) r[type] = [{ type, ...rest }];
      else if(r[type].length < slice[type]) r[type].push({ type, ...rest })
    }
    return r;
  }, {})

  return [].concat(...Object.values(obj))
}

console.log(sliceArr(a, { t1: 3, t2: 4 }))
```